# How to theme PDF generated by Print module?

Tags: 7

I would like to theme the PDF generated by the Print module. I would like to add header, footer, margins, border to the generated PDF.

The certificate module in Drupal provides theming to the certificate, but my site is almost like a read and get certified site, so I wish not to change print module.

I tried the form alter and other stuffs, but not sure from where the PDF can be changed.

Comment: Have u tried TCPDF?

Comment: If you want to theme pdf as per your site design, then you need to use `wkhtmltopdf` to generate pdf template.

Comment: @Harshal : Yes I am using TCPDF, but still I am not sure where the contents get generated in the PDF. There exits no hook or alter to explain this.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola: I am using TCPDF, that should work. But still I will try the wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: @Gladiator, as per my understanding, TCPDF does not support your custom css.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola: I am partially aware about the lack of CSS support in TCPDF, but it does provides some API type of function to theme. Hence I am sticking to TCPDF.

Comment: YOu should go through this link http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html

Comment: @Gladiator, Ok. I have not worked with `TCPDF`, so not aware about this.

Comment: http://www.blog.yamandi.com/print-module-drupal-generate-pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 7 allows to alter how content is rendered with `theme_print_pdf_tcpdf_content()`. This should be fairly simple: Just place this hook in the template.php file, and add a new function where the PDF file is rendered. Use the following code as reference.

```php
function theme_print_pdf_tcpdf_content(&$vars) {  
  return new_function_that_prints_the_content($vars); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should on your creation of node call a function which will generate a pdf.
Use tcpdf class for it generate pdf and download  tcpdf functions./
Check also the [link](http://www.cameronandwilding.com/blog/jos%C3%A9/custom-pdf-generation-tcpdf)

```
 class my_pdf extends TCPDF { //Page header public function Header() { } // Page footer public function Footer() { } } 

$pdf = new my_pdf(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, UTF-8', false);

$pdf->setPrintHeader(true);
 $pdf->setPrintFooter(true); 
$pdf->SetMargins(25.0, 40, 25.0);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(1.5);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 50);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, ''); 
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('my_document.pdf', 'D');
```

Comment: @Gladiator have u tried this?

Comment: Not yet will try now and will keep you updated. Thanks for the code.

Comment: check the link for the explanation..

Answer (score 2):

Print module comes with a print-pdf.tpl.php template as well as a print.tpl.php template (or use the one in your theme).
Since this is all about styling, rather look at editing these and put them in your theme folder.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually possible using a hook for TCPDF:

```
/**
 * Implements hook__print_pdf_tcpdf_alter()
 */
function MODULENAME_print_pdf_tcpdf_alter($pdf, $html, $meta) {
  $pdf->setPrintHeader(FALSE);
  $pdf->SetPrintFooter(FALSE);
}
```